# Ios Swift : Displaying Navigation Bar in custom Tabbar

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am trying to create a custom tab bar to place it on top of the screen using below code, programmatically. But the problem is, i am not able to get a navigation bar on top of the tabbar to go back to previous screen.
kindly help me.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let SrnBrdVar = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let TabBarCtrVar = UITabBarController()
    let TabBarVar = TabBarCtrVar.tabBar
    let ObxSrnVar = SrnBrdVar.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ObxSrnUid")
    let ObxNavSrnVar = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ObxSrnVar)
    let IbxSrnVar = SrnBrdVar.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IbxSrnUid")
    let IbxNavSrnVar = UINavigationController(rootViewController: IbxSrnVar)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window?!.rootViewController = TabBarCtrVar

    ObxSrnVar.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
        title: "Outbox",
        image: UIImage(named: "NamItmDftImj"),
        selectedImage: UIImage(named: "NamItmSltImj")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal))
    IbxSrnVar.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
        title: "Inbox",
        image: UIImage(named: "NamItmDftImj"),
        selectedImage: UIImage(named: "NamItmSltImj")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal))

    TabBarCtrVar.viewControllers = [ObxSrnVar,IbxSrnVar]

    TabBarVar.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    TabBarVar.frame = CGRectMake(
        0,
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height + 64,
        UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width,
        50)
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a TabBar Controller programatically and then add to it navigation bar (programatically as well)?

Comment: I need all Childview controllers (Inbox and Outbox) to inherit Navigation bar from Parent Custom tabbar (abv) view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Hopefully it will be useful for you as well

```
 let myStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let myTabBarController = UITabBarController()

    let leftController = myStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("left")

    let leftNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftController)

    let rightController = myStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("right")

    let rightNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rightController)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window?!.rootViewController = myTabBarController

    myTabBarController.addChildViewController(leftNavController)
    myTabBarController.addChildViewController(rightNavController)



    let leftChild = myStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("leftChild")
    let rightChild = myStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("rightChild")


    leftNavController.addChildViewController(leftChild)
    rightNavController.addChildViewController(rightChild)

    print(myTabBarController.viewControllers?.count)
   let but1 = myTabBarController.viewControllers?[0].tabBarItem
    but1!.title = "Left Page"
    let but2 = myTabBarController.viewControllers?[1].tabBarItem
        but2!.title = "Right Page"


    leftNavController.childViewControllers[0].navigationItem.title = "Left View"
    rightNavController.childViewControllers[0].navigationItem.title = "Right View"
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me to get navigation bar. But i am not able to add back button and make it work to move to previous screen.
Can anyone help me with this.

```
    let SrnBrdVar = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let TabBarCtrVar = UITabBarController()
    let TabBarVar = TabBarCtrVar.tabBar
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window?!.rootViewController = TabBarCtrVar

    let Tab1SrnVar = SrnBrdVar.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Tab1SrnXid")
    let Tab2SrnVar = SrnBrdVar.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Tab2SrnXid")

    let Tab1NavCtrVar = UINavigationController(rootViewController: Tab1SrnVar)
    let Tab2NavCtrVar = UINavigationController(rootViewController: Tab2SrnVar)

    Tab1NavCtrVar.childViewControllers[0].navigationItem.title = "Nam1TabSrn"
    Tab2NavCtrVar.childViewControllers[0].navigationItem.title = "Nam2TabSrn"

    Tab1NavCtrVar.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
        title: "Nam1Tab",
        image: UIImage(named: "NamItmDftImj"),
        selectedImage: UIImage(named: "NamItmSltImj")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal))
    Tab2NavCtrVar.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
        title: "Nam2Tab",
        image: UIImage(named: "NamItmDftImj"),
        selectedImage: UIImage(named: "NamItmSltImj")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal))

    TabBarCtrVar.viewControllers = [Tab1NavCtrVar,Tab2NavCtrVar]

    TabBarVar.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    TabBarVar.frame = CGRectMake(
        0,
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height + 40,
        UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width,
        50)
```